# How can we show that $\left\{x\mapsto\prod_{i=1}^kf_i(x_i):f_i\in C_0(E_i)\right\}$ is convergence determining on $\times_{i=1}^ kE_i$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $E$ be a complete locally compact separable metric space and $\mu,\mu_n$ be probability measures on $\mathcal B(E)$. We say $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly if $$\int f\:{\rm d}\mu_n\to\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\tag1$$ for all bounded continuous $f:E\to\mathbb R$ (write $f\in C_b(E)$) and we say $\mu_n\to\mu$ vaguely if $(1)$ for all compactly supported continuous $f:E\to\mathbb R$ (write $f\in C_c(E)$).

> By the Portmanteau theorem, $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly if and only if $\mu_n\to\mu$ vaguely *and* $\mu(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(E)$.

Now, we say that $M\subseteq C_b(E)$ is *convergence determining* if the assertion that $(1)$ holds for all $f\in M$ implies $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly. By Proposition 4.4 of Chapter 3 in the book of Ethier/Kurtz, $C_c(E)$ is convergence determining. But that means (by our definition) $\mu_n\to\mu$ vaguely.

> **Question 1**: Am I missing something or does that mean that in the Portmanteau theorem we are able to conclude $\mu_n\to\mu$ vaguely *and* $\mu(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(E)$ from $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly, while we only need to know $\mu_n\to\mu$ vaguely in order to conclude $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly?

Now assume we have complete locally compact separable metric spaces $E_1,\ldots,E_k$. I would like to show that $$\tilde M:=\left\{\prod_{i=1}^k(f_i\circ\pi_i):f_i\in C_0(E_i)\right\},$$ where $\pi_i:\times_{j=1}^dE_j\to E_i$ is the projection onto the $i$th coordinate) is convergence determining (on $\times_{i=1}^kE_i$). Again in Ethier/Kurtz, Proposition 4.6 of Chapter 3, we find the claim that if $M_i\subseteq C_b(E_i)$ is convergence determining (on $E_i$), then $$M:=\left\{\prod_{i=1}^k(f_i\circ\pi_i):f_i\in M_i\cup\color{red}{\left\{1\right\}}\right\}$$ is convergence determining. I would clearly take $M_i=C_0(E_i)$ (which is convergence determining by the former result and since $C_c(E_i)$ is dense in $C_0(E_i)$ by definition). However, Ethier/Kurtz allow $f_i$ to be the constant function $1$ (which is clearly not in $C_0(E_i)$, unless $E_i$ is compact). They state Proposition 4.6 in the more general case of a countable product, but I don't think that this is the reason why we need to allow $f_i\equiv 1$. On the other hand, taking $k=1$ yields a result weaker than what we assume beforehand (we start with $M_1$ being convergence determining and conclude $M_1\cup\left\{1\right\}$ is convergence determining).

> **Question 2**: What am I missing here? Is my $\tilde M$ convergence determining?

Comment: The vague topology uses continuous functions that vanish at infinity, not only continuous functions with compact support. Notice that the two classes of "test functions" [give different topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vague_topology). Where did you take your definition from? Also, where did you take that version of the Portmanteau theorem from? [The one I know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) does not say what yours says.

Comment: For question 1, note that $\mu_n(E) = \mu(E) = 1$ since these things are assumed to be probability measures.

Comment: @AlexM. It's true that the two classes of "test functions" give different topologies on the space complex Radon measures but as far as convergence goes, when restricted to probability measures the two classes of "test functions" at least give the same notion of convergence which is possibly the reason OP (or their source) isn't careful here (you can prove this using a similar technique as in my answer to the second question of OP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:** The point is that in the definition of a set being convergence determining you make the additional assumption that $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are probability measures and so the thing you call the Portmanteau Theorem (which is true but is not the thing I would call the Portmanteau Theorem) says that $\mu_n \to \mu$ vaguely if and only if $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly (under the extra assumption). Unfortunately, the space of probability measures isn't closed in the vague topology on the space of, say, finite measures but is closed in the weak topology. To make this concrete, take $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_n = \delta_n$ to be the point mass at $n$. Then $\mu_n \to 0$ vaguely and not weakly, the problem being that $C_0(E)$ is failing to capture "the escape of mass to infinity" which is exactly what the extra condition in what you call the Portmanteau Theorem fixes.

**Question 2:** The only thing that we can't do in the same way when we don't allow ourselves the function $1$ in the proof of Proposition 4.6 of Chapter 3 of Ethier and Kurtz is immediately conclude that for $f_i \in M_i$, 
$$\int f_i d\mu_n \to \int f_i d\mu$$
whenever $\mu_n, \mu$ satisfy $(1)$ for all $f \in \tilde{M}$. The extra structure on your equivalent of $M_i$ allows you to get around this. For (notational) convenience, I will demonstrate the idea in the case $k = 2$ and $i = 1$. I imagine this proof can be simplified significantly.

Fix an $\varepsilon > 0$. Also fix strictly increasing sequences $(K_n^i)_{n \geq 1}$ of compact subsets of $E_i$ that cover $E_i$ and satisfy $d(\partial K_n^i, \partial K_{n+1}^i) > 0$ (such compact exhaustions exists since $E_i$ is a locally compact separable metric space, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45687/locally-compact-separable-metric-spaces)). Then since $\mu$ is a probability measure, there is an $N_\varepsilon$ such that 
$$\mu(K_{N_\varepsilon}^1 \times K_{N_\varepsilon}^2) \geq 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$

Now take continuous functions $f_i^{(\varepsilon)}$ valued in $[0,1]$ such that $f_i^{(\varepsilon)} = 1$ on $K_{N_\varepsilon}^i$ and $f_i^{(\varepsilon)} = 0 $ outside of $K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^i $. Then $f_i^{(\varepsilon)} \in C_c(E_i) \subseteq C_0(E_i)$ so
$$\int f_1^{(\varepsilon)} f_2^{(\varepsilon)} d \mu_n \to \int f_1^{(\varepsilon)} f_2^{(\varepsilon)} d \mu \geq 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
so for large enough $n$,
$$\mu_n(K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^1 \times K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^2) \geq \int f_1^{(\varepsilon)} f_2^{(\varepsilon)} d \mu_n \geq 1 - \varepsilon.$$
Now pick continuous, compactly supported functions $g_i^{(\varepsilon)}$ valued in $[0,1]$ such that $g_i^{(\varepsilon)} = 1$ on $K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^i$.

Then, we can bound
\begin{align}
\bigg | \int_{E_1 \times E_2} f_1 d \mu_n - \int_{E_1 \times E_2} f_1 d \mu \bigg| & \leq \bigg | \int f_1 - f_1 g_1^{(\varepsilon)} g_2^{(\varepsilon)} d \mu \bigg| + \bigg | \int   f_1 g_1^{(\varepsilon)} g_2^{(\varepsilon)} d( \mu - \mu_n ) \bigg| \\ &+ \bigg | \int f_1 - f_1 g_1^{(\varepsilon)} g_2^{(\varepsilon)} d \mu_n \bigg|
\end{align}
Now the first and last terms are each bounded by $\|f\|_\infty \varepsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large, by our choice of $g_i^{(\varepsilon)}$. The middle term goes to $0$ since $f_1 g_1^{(\varepsilon)} \in C_0(E_1)$ and $g_2^{(\varepsilon)} \in C_0(E_2)$ and so for large enough $n$ we have
$$\bigg | \int_{E_1 \times E_2} f_1 d \mu_n - \int_{E_1 \times E_2} f_1 d \mu \bigg| \leq (2 \|f_1\|_\infty + 1) \varepsilon$$
which gives the desired convergence.

Comment: Regarding question 2: I get the point that it's not evident that $\int f_i\circ\pi_i\:{\rm d}\mu_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int f_i\circ\pi_i\:{\rm d}\mu$ for all $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}$ from knowing that $(1)$ holds for all $f\in\tilde M$. You've proved that we may establish this. But how exactly is this related to the question whether $\tilde M$ is convergence determining or not? Is it convergence determining?

Comment: @0xbadf00d As I say in the answer, the point is that this is the **only** thing that is not evident in your case if we try to follow the proof of proposition 4.6 to see where it goes wrong (which should be the first thing to try when you have slightly different hypotheses like this). So once you've understood my answer just read that proof in Ethier and Kurtz but with your hypotheses and you'll see it just works.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: How do you obtain $\mu(K_{N_\varepsilon}^1 \times K_{N_\varepsilon}^2) \geq 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$? Assuming $k=1$, it's clear to me that $1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(K_n^1)$ and hence for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ with $\mu(K_n)>1-\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. But it's not clear to me on the product space, since $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\times_{i=1}^kK_n^{i}\ne\times_{i=1}^k\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_0}K_n^{i}=E$.

Comment: Actually it is not hard to see that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \times_{i=1}^k K_n^i = \times_{i=1}^k \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n^i$ here because the $K_n^i$ are chosen to be increasing (that was one reason for that choice). For simplicity in the case $k = 2$, $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n^1 \times \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n^2 = \bigcup_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^2} K_n^1 \times K_m^2$ and e.g. if $n < m$ then $K_n^1 \subset K_m^1$ so $K_n^1 \times K_m^2 \subset K_m^1 \times K_m^2$. The case $m<n$ is almost identical so you get the nontrivial inclusion.

Comment: Ah, sure. I guess now you've chosen the factor $\frac12$ in $\mu(K_{N_\varepsilon}^1 \times K_{N_\varepsilon}^2) \geq 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ just for cosmetics. It lead me on a wrong track since I thought it would correspond to the fact that we're considering a product of $2$ spaces.

Comment: I chose the factor $\frac12$ because it is the first obvious choice that is smaller than $1$ (not an uncommon thing to happen). I make a slight loss in the bounds later when I get a lower bound of the form $1 - \varepsilon$ so this is just anticipating that loss. It should be obvious that this isn't about the number of spaces in the product if you follow why I wrote $\geq 1- \varepsilon$ rather than $\geq 1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ the first time I do this.

Comment: I know a version of Urysohn's lemma which that if $A,B$ are subsets of a metric space $(X,d_X)$, with $A\subseteq B$, $A$ being closed and nonempty and $B\ne X$ being open, then there is a $f\in C(X,[0,1]$ with $\left.f\right|_A=0$ and $\left.f\right|_{B^c}=1$. We could apply this to $A=K_{N_\varepsilon}^i$ and $B=\operatorname{int}\left(K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^i\right)$, but that does yield $\left.f\right|_{K_{N_\varepsilon}^i}=0$ and $\left.f\right|_{E_i\setminus K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^i}=1$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the point of your last comment. Are you asking why my functions $f_i^{(\varepsilon)}$ exist?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: It is trivial that such functions exist. Of course, we could take $1-f$ with $f$ as in your previous comment but this is far too much machinery for the problem. The conclusion of Urysohn's lemma is trivial if the boundaries of your sets are separated. Since $d(\partial K_{N_\varepsilon}^i, \partial K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^i) > 0$ we can take $f_i^{(\varepsilon)}(x) = \min \{1, d(\partial K_{N_\varepsilon}^i, \partial K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^i)^{-1} \cdot d(x, (K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^i)^c)\}$.

Comment: It's clear to me that $f_i^{\varepsilon}$ is $0$ on $E_i\setminus K^i_{N_\varepsilon+1}$, but why is it $1$ on $K_{N_\varepsilon}^i$? This is precisely the case when $d_i\left(x,E_i\setminus K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^{(i)}\right)\ge d_i\left(\partial K_{N_\varepsilon}^{(i)},\partial K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^{(i)}\right)$ for all $x\in K_{N_\varepsilon}^{(i)}$. The only related inclusion seems to be $E_i\setminus K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^{(i)}\subseteq E_i\setminus\operatorname{int}\left(K_{N_\varepsilon+1}^{(i)}\right)\subseteq E_i\setminus K_{N_\varepsilon}^{(i)}$,  but that doesn't help immediately.

Comment: Fine, take $f_i^{(\varepsilon)} = \min \{1, d(K_{N_\varepsilon^i}, (K_{N_\varepsilon}^i)^c)^{-1} \cdot d(x, (K_{N_\varepsilon}^i)^c)\}$. I made a small error because I didn't want to spend any time on that comment. This is standard metric spaces stuff that you should think about for yourself.

Comment: When you write $\int f_1^{(ε)}f_2^{(ε)}dμ$, you actually mean $\int(f_1^{(ε)}∘π_1)(f_2^{(ε)}∘π_2){\rm d}μ$, right? From which of the assumptions do you conclude $\int(f_1^{(ε)}∘π_1)(f_2^{(ε)}∘π_2){\rm d}μ_n\xrightarrow{n→∞}\int(f_1^{(ε)}∘π_1)(f_2^{(ε)}∘π_2){\rm d}μ$? It should follow by our assumption that $\intφ\:{\rm d}μ_n\xrightarrow{n→∞}\intφ\:{\rm d}μ$ for all $φ∈\tilde M$. But since you're explicitly stressing the fact that $f_i^{(ε)}\in C_c(E_i)⊆C_0(E_i)$ it seems like you've got something else in mind. I'm just asking out of curiosity and to make sure I'm not missing something crucial.

Comment: No one really writes the $\pi_i$ when writing an integral of a function of a single variable against a measure on a product space. You can put it there if you want. It is literally your assumption. To apply the assumption you require that $f_i^{(\varepsilon)} \in C_)(E_i)$ which is what I check. You should try to check these things for yourself. I won't be answering anymore of your questions here because the details of this answer are all quite clear and it seems that instead of trying to understand them you are just asking more and more questions about simple details.

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason I was thinking that the $f_i$ in the definition of $\tilde M$ belong to $C_c(E_i)$ - that led to my confusion.

Comment: Maybe you're willing to respond to the following note: I think that the we only need that the sequence $(K_n^i)_{n≥1}$ is nondecreasing, consists of compact subsets and covers $E_i$. Everything else (in particular, strict inclusions and $d_i(∂K_n^i,∂K_{n+1}^i)>0$) is not used in the argumentation. Moreover, we only need to assume that $f^{(ε)}_i∈C_c(E_i)$ satisfies $0≤f^{(ε)}_i≤1$ and $\left.f^{(ε)}_i\right|_{K_{N_ε}^i}=1$. You don't use $\left.f^{(ε)}_i\right|_{K_{N_ε+1}^i}=0$ anywhere. If you agree, I would really appreciate if you let me know.

Comment: I use $\left.f^{(ε)}_i\right|_{(K_{N_ε+1}^i)^c}=0$ to see that $f_i^{(\varepsilon)} C_c(E_i)$. Maybe you can manage with weaker hypotheses on $K_{n}^i$ if you allow yourself Urysohn's lemma (I avoided it since I didn't know if you were familiar with it). However, you do need to do something to ensure that the constructed functions vanish at infinity which will involve a smallness condition outside of compact sets. Also to use your form of Urysohn's lemma you also need to ensure that $K_N^i \subseteq \operatorname{int} K_{N+1}^i$ which isn't obvious to me without the distance condition.

Comment: Yes, I need to admit that we need $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}^\circ$. Then we can choose $\varphi:=\frac{d\left(\;\cdot\;,E\setminus K_{n+1}^\circ\right)}{d\left(\;\cdot\;,E\setminus K_n\right)+d\left(\;\cdot\;,E\setminus K_{n+1}^\circ\right)}$. Then $\left.\varphi\right|_{K_n}\equiv1$ and $\left.\varphi\right|_{E\setminus K_{n+1}^\circ}\equiv0$. Clearly, $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}^\circ$ implies the strict inclusion $K_n\subset K_{n+1}$ and the distance condition. (I've omitted the index $i$ above for simplicity.)

Comment: I've completely understood the proof given in Ethier for our modified $\tilde M$ now, but there is one remaining issue: We need that $\tilde M$ is separating. How do we need to modify the proof of that?

Comment: Why? I don't see you needing that to prove that $\tilde{M}$ is convergence determining anywhere.

Comment: It is needed to conclude $\mu_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu$ from the relative compactness. It is an assumption of Lemma 4.3 which is used by Ethier and Kurtz at the end of their proof.

Comment: Have you actually read the proof of (a)? Before bothering me you should at least be able to tell me what goes wrong in it if we have your hypotheses.

Comment: Sure, it starts with the question whether $C_0(E)$ is separating.

Comment: Check the discussion immediately after the definitions of convergence determining and separating again. The first implies the second.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Each $C_0(E_i)$ is separating, but the main problem is the following: Let $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal P(E)$ with $$\mu f=\nu f\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\tilde M\tag2.$$ Now let $B_i\in\mathcal B(E_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,k$. The goal is to show $\mu(B_1\times\cdots\times B_k)=\nu(B_1\times\cdots\times B_k)$. We claim the following: Let $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and $f_i\in C_0(E_i)$, $i=j+1,\ldots,k$. Then $$\int\prod_{i=1}^j1_{B_i}(x_i)\prod_{i=j+1}^kf_i(x_i)\:\mu({\rm d}(x_1,\ldots,x_k))=\int\prod_{i=1}^j1_{B_i}(x_i)\prod_{i=j+1}^kf_i(x_i)\:\nu({\rm d}(x_1,\ldots,x_k))\tag3.$$

Comment: Using $(2)$ and that $C_0(E_i)$ is separating, this is easily seen for $j=1$. The problem is in the induction step, since it seems like we need to insert a $1$ in order to utilize $(2)$ again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93780/discussion-between-rhys-steele-and-0xbadf00d).

Comment: Am I missing something or can we replace $C_0(E_i)$ in the definiton of $\tilde M$ by $C_c(E_i)$? I think every argument was made by noting that $C_c(E_i)$ is contained in $C_0(E_i)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, this proof is really for $C_c(E_i)$ instead of $C_0(E_i)$. I had that in mind when writing it since it is no more difficult so I wanted the proof to work in that case too.